# WCF some methods decorated with OperationContract not showing up (not exposed) to client

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS on Windows Server 2016 using Framework 4.6.01586. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with the latest service pack.

I've got two methods in my interface decorated with [OperationContract] - the GetData and InsertData methods. My service is up and running and I can browse the SVC with no problem and see the WSDL. I created a C# client application and added a service reference to the service.

```
Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
string result = client.
```

And that's where my problem is. After the period in the line of code above I should see both the GetData and InsertData methods available to add, but I'm only seeing the GetData method. Again, both methods in the service interface are decorated with their own [OperationContract] tags, and when I look in the WSDL I do see both methods listed, so I'm at a loss as to why the InsertData method isn't showing up.

```
namespace DatabaseService1
     [ServiceContract]
     public interface IService1
     {
          [OperationContract]
          string GetData(string value);

          [OperationContract]
          string InsertData(string value);
     }

     [DataContract]
     …
}
```

I'm probably missing something simple but I can't figure it out. I've made sure that I rebuilt the service and the client.

Comment: Have you updated the service reference in your client project? In Solution Explorer, right click the service reference (in the client project), and click "Update Service Reference".

Comment: Ugh! I knew it would probably be something simple, but not that simple. I assumed that the service reference would be dynamic and update when the project was compiled. That's what I get for assuming. Thanks for the answer, Polyfun!